# How to get human friendly format time zone offset (PHP)

Tags: php, symfony, datetime, time, timezone-offset

Help me to decide this task, please. (PHP, Symfony)

What I have:
List of time zone like

```
"Europe/Riga"
"Europe/Rome"
"Europe/Samara"
"Europe/San_Marino"
"Europe/Sarajevo"
```

In result I want to see:

```
 (+00:00) Riga
 (+01:30) Rome
 (+03:00) Samara
 (-01:00) San_Marino
 (+05:00) Sarajevo
```

What I did:

```
$timeZoneIdentifierList = DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers();

        $timeZoneUtc = new DateTimeZone('UTC');
        $nowByUtc = new DateTime('now', $timeZoneUtc);

        foreach ($timeZoneIdentifierList as $timeZoneIdentifier) {
            $dateTimezoneItem = new DateTimeZone($timeZoneIdentifier);

            $timeZone = $dateTimezoneItem->getOffset($nowByUtc);
            
            $humanFriendlyOffset = $timeZone / 3600;
        }
```

And if I dump $**humanFriendlyOffset** I get only digital value like this: 0, 1, -7, 2, 1.5

**Question**:
Is something prepared method in PHP/Symfony to convert

- 1 -> +01:00,
- -7 -> -07:00,
- 2 -> +02:00,
- 1.5 -> +01:30

May be exist more easy way?

Comment: "human friendly" probably means "not having to get up before noon", right?

Comment: you are right %)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution creates a new DateTime object for each time zone.

```
$tzArr = ["Europe/Riga",
"Europe/Rome",
"Europe/Samara",
"Europe/San_Marino",
"Europe/Sarajevo",
"UTC"];

foreach($tzArr as $tz){
  $dt = date_create('Now',new DateTimeZone($tz));
  
  $formatTz = $dt->format('\(P\) e');
  echo $formatTz."<br>\n"; 
}
```

Output:

```
(+02:00) Europe/Riga
(+01:00) Europe/Rome
(+04:00) Europe/Samara
(+01:00) Europe/San_Marino
(+01:00) Europe/Sarajevo
(+00:00) UTC
```

With a preg_replace the continent can be hidden and an output can be achieved exactly as desired.

```
foreach($tzArr as $tz){
  $dt = date_create('Now',new DateTimeZone($tz));

  $loc = preg_replace('~^[a-z]+/~i','', $dt->format('e'));
  $formatTz = $dt->format('\(P\) ').$loc;
  echo $formatTz."<br>\n"; 
}
```

Output:

```
(+02:00) Riga
(+01:00) Rome
(+04:00) Samara
(+01:00) San_Marino
(+01:00) Sarajevo
(+00:00) UTC
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `P` formatter from [DateTimeInterface::format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) to get a friendly timezone offset, but that's on a DateTime object, not a DateTimeZone object. So you could create a DateTime object, then explicitly set its timezone to the one you want, then get its offset. Something like this

```
$dt = new DateTime();
foreach (DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers() as $tz) {
    $dt->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone($tz));
    printf("(%s) %s\n", $dt->format('P'), $tz);
}
```

Output:

```
(+00:00) Africa/Abidjan
(+00:00) Africa/Accra
(+03:00) Africa/Addis_Ababa
(+01:00) Africa/Algiers
(+03:00) Africa/Asmara
(+00:00) Africa/Bamako
(+01:00) Africa/Bangui
(+00:00) Africa/Banjul
(+00:00) Africa/Bissau
```